# Adicionar multiplos Documentos ao Firestore, através de um Map

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-database, firestore

Olá. Tenho um firestore com a seguinte estrutura:

bd:
   alunos:
      matricula
         dado1
         dado2
         dado3

Alunos é uma coleção, e cada matrícula é um documento. tenho um hashmap de , onde a string é a matricula, ou seja, o nome do documento. quero adicionar estes documentos sem um laço, apenas com um comendo. oq estou usando é:

```
db.collection("alunos").add(alunos.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Aluno::getMatricula, c -> c)));
```

porém, quando vou olhar no meu banco de dados o resultado final, ele criou:

alunos -> id aleatorio gerado por ele -> campos com (dados:valor).

estou estruturando erro o bd, ou tem como eu fzer isto funcionar?